# group by day and time in sql BigQuery

Tags: sql, time, group-by, google-bigquery, timestamp

The data needs to be grouped by Time within 1 minute interval. Data:

```
id            time                  
111      2020-09-01-09:19:00         
111      2020-09-01-09:19:04        
111      2020-09-01-09:19:08     
112      2020-09-01-10:12:05       
111      2020-09-02-12:36:54     
111      2020-09-02-12:36:58     
111      2020-09-02-12:37:03     
111      2020-09-02-12:37:09
```

The desired output is:

```
id            time                         
111      2020-09-01-09:19:08     
112      2020-09-01-10:12:05           
111      2020-09-02-12:37:09
```

I have tried:

```
SELECT id, TIMESTAMP(time) 
FROM my_table
GROUP BY id, (DATEPART(MINUTE, [time]) / 1)
```

`Function not found: DATEPART`

Comment: do  you really have time column formatted this way `2020-09-01-09:19:00` ? please confirm/clarify

Comment: Actually, this is a string... So you are right. I just edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

> The data needs to be grouped by Time within 1 minute interval.

For this question, you can use `timestamp_trunc()` (or `datetime_trunc()`):

```
select max(timestamp_trunc(time, minute)), id
from t
group by timestamp_trunc(time, minute), id;
```

This does not, however, return the results that you specify.

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT AS VALUE 
  ARRAY_AGG(t ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)]
FROM `project.dataset.my_table` t
GROUP BY id, 
  TIMESTAMP_SUB(
    PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S', time), 
    INTERVAL MOD(UNIX_SECONDS(PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S', time)), 2 * 60) 
    SECOND
  )
```

You can test, play with above using sample data form y our question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.my_table` AS (
  SELECT 111 id, '2020-09-01-09:19:00' time UNION ALL
  SELECT 111, '2020-09-01-09:19:04' UNION ALL
  SELECT 111, '2020-09-01-09:19:08' UNION ALL
  SELECT 112, '2020-09-01-10:12:05' UNION ALL
  SELECT 111, '2020-09-01-12:36:54' UNION ALL
  SELECT 111, '2020-09-01-12:36:58' UNION ALL
  SELECT 111, '2020-09-01-12:37:03' UNION ALL
  SELECT 111, '2020-09-01-12:37:09' 
)
SELECT AS VALUE 
  ARRAY_AGG(t ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)]
FROM `project.dataset.my_table` t
GROUP BY id, 
  TIMESTAMP_SUB(
    PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S', time), 
    INTERVAL MOD(UNIX_SECONDS(PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S', time)), 2 * 60) 
    SECOND
  )
```

with output

```
Row     id      time     
1       111     2020-09-01-09:19:08  
2       112     2020-09-01-10:12:05  
3       111     2020-09-01-12:37:09
```

Note: to match your expected output  - you should use 2 min interval instead of 1 minute interval